# Java получение ресурсов из jar и нет

Tags: java, jar, resources

В общем ситуация такая: я делаю обертку для дальнейшего приложения, суть обертки - возможность расширения приложения плагинами, для безопасности (чтоб плагин не мог влиять на ядро) надо сделать систему с иерархией загрузчиков:

      Bootstrap 
              |
       Common CL
   /               |          \
AppCore  Plugin1  PluginN
В классе Bootstrap для загрузки API плагинов необходимо получить файлы директории common
делаю я это так:

```
URI uri = Bootstrap.class.getResource(Bootstrap.class.getSimpleName() +".class").toURI
if (!"jar".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) { //не в jar
        logger.severe("Source \"" + Bootstrap.class.getSimpleName() + ".class\" is not in a jar file!");
    }
try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap())) {
   Files.list(fs.getPath("/")).forEach(System.out::println);//выводим список фалов
```

проблема в том что этот код работает только когда запускается из jar, при отладке и запуске через ide он не работает и выдает ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'
```

хотя `System.out.println(uri.getPath());`  дает верный путь  вида `/D:/WORKSPACE/PluginIncludingSave/out/production/PluginIncludingSave/load/Bootstrap.class`

Я понимаю что это связано с тем что ide пускает код не из jar

Вопрос, есть ли возможность как то обойти это, чтоб код, получающий директорию и потом список файлов в ней, одинаково работал и в ide и в jar ( возможно сделать 2 варианта получения этой директории)?
В инете ничего дельного не нашел, все предлагают использование потока и `getResourceAsStream();` Но я не нашел как через `InputStream`получить содержимое директории и потом загружать файлы или получать `url` для `UrlClassLoader-а`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список файлов директории MyDir в jar и в production

```
 URI u = MyClass.class.getResource(MyClass.class.getSimpleName() + ".class").toURI();
    FileSystem f;
    String s;
    if ("jar".equalsIgnoreCase(u.getScheme())) {
        f = FileSystems.newFileSystem(u, Collections.emptyMap());
        s = "/";
    } else {
        //Класс не в jar значит берем ФС системы пишем в префикс путь к папке в которую IDE кладет .class
        f = Paths.get(u).getFileSystem();
        s = u.getPath().substring(3).substring(0, u.getPath().lastIndexOf("MyClassDir") - 3);
    }
    Files.list(f.getPath(s + "MyDir")).forEach(System.out::println);//список фалов директории MyDir 
    f.close();
```

Структура директории production:
[Директория проекта]
   ├[MyClassDir]
   │   └MyClass.class
   ├[MyDir]
   │   └(ваши файлы)
   ├[META-INF]
   (Другие файлы и директории)